# System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Cannot find table 0

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, ajax, sql-server-2008

Dal code

```
 public DataSet selectlogin(string u_name, string u_password, string u_email, string action)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(h);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "sp_login";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", u_name);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", u_email);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", u_password);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@action", action);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    ad.Fill(ds);
    return ds;
    con.Close();
}
```

Bal code

```
 public DataSet selectlogin(string u_name, string u_password, string u_email, string action)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds = obj.selectlogin(u_name, u_password, u_email, action);
        return ds;
    }
```

CS code

```
protected void Btn_log(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        ds = obj.selectlogin("", TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text,"login");

        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Response.Redirect("dashboard.aspx");
        }


    }
```

Stored procedure

```
if(@action='login')

select * from login where u_email=@email and u_pass=@password
```

Comment: You might want to give more Text regarding your issue.

Comment: Hmm.. nice code! Is there a problem with the code? Or is it just to show us your code?

Comment: Looks like you don't have a table 0, maybe you should add one? What do you expect to get out of posting this code here?

Comment: What happen if there is no user with the email and password provided? No tables are returned inside the dataset, so you cannot use a table at index zero because there is none

Answer (score 1):

The trouble might be here:

```
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
```

First check if the table with the index of 0 exists, then try to access the properties...

```
if (ds.Tables.Count > 0 && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0 )
```

This should help. Or at least it'll tell you that the returned dataset is empty (has no tables inside).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
protected void Btn_log(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        ds = obj.selectlogin("", TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text,"login");
    bool hasRows = ds.Tables.Cast<DataTable>()
                               .Any(table => table.Rows.Count != 0);
        if (hasRows)
        {
            Response.Redirect("dashboard.aspx");
        }

    }
```

Or try it( **use != operator instead of > operator**)

```
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count **!=** 0)
        {
            Response.Redirect("dashboard.aspx");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

CS code

```
protected void Btn_log(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    ds = obj.selectlogin("", TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text,"login");

    if (ds!=null && ds.Tables[0].Count > 0 && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        Response.Redirect("dashboard.aspx");
    }
}
```